# Match records between dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i hope someone can give me a hand here

I have two regions, on the left a list of items and a range of dates, the other one is a table with one date, i want to generate the "dev" yellow field using a formula (if possible)

[image]

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `INDEX`/`MATCH` as array formula:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$5,MATCH(1,(F2=$A$2:$A$5)*(G2>=$C$2:$C$5)*(G2<=$D$2:$D$5),0))
```

or `INDEX`/`AGGREGATE` as conventional formula:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$5,AGGREGATE(14,6,(F2=$A$2:$A$5)*(G2>=$C$2:$C$5)*(G2<=$D$2:$D$5)*ROW($B$2:$B$5)-1,1))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]